# Issue in reorder checkout fields woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields");

function order_fields($fields) {

$order = array(
    "billing_first_name",
    "billing_last_name",
    "billing_company",
    "billing_email",
    "billing_country",
    "billing_address_1",
    "billing_state",
    "billing_postcode",
    "billing_city"   
);
foreach($order as $field)
{
    $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
}

$fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
return $fields;

}
```

On refreshing page is show what I want but when page fully load fields order becomes as before. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need set priority along with reordering. Try this.

```
    add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields",99);

    function order_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(
        "billing_first_name"=>10,
        "billing_last_name"=>20,
        "billing_company"=>30,
        "billing_email"=>40,
        "billing_country"=>50,
        "billing_address_1"=>60,
        "billing_state"=>70,
        "billing_postcode"=>80,
        "billing_city=>90"   
    );
    foreach($order as $field=>$priority)
    {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
        $ordered_fields[$field]['priority']=$priority;
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It reorder all fields except email field.

Answer (score 0):

```
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'bbloomer_move_checkout_fields_woo_3' );

function bbloomer_move_checkout_fields_woo_3( $fields ) {

  $fields['first_name']['priority'] = 10;
  $fields['last_name']['priority'] = 20;
  $fields['company']['priority'] = 30;
  $fields['email']['priority'] = 35;
  $fields['country']['priority'] = 40;
  $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 50;
  $fields['state']['priority'] = 60;
  $fields['postcode']['priority'] = 70;
  $fields['city']['priority'] = 80;

  return $fields;
}
function ld_wc_filter_billing_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_email']['priority'] = 35;
    return $address_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'ld_wc_filter_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
```

I have search alot and get this code. This code fine for me what I want.